# Eclipse compare local versions

Tags: eclipse, svn

In Eclipse, I am trying to compare local versions, but it just shows this empty, blue pane.  Any suggestions?

[eclipse screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDlCV.png)

Comment: Try another date, may they are identical.

Comment: Your Eclipse looks pretty outdated. Please upgrade to avoid bugs fixed long time ago.